# Cant leverage cache browser using wordpress and .htacces

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, caching

I have the following code in my wordpress .htacces

```
    ## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 days"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

However its not working, im still having lots of caching errors in Google Pagespeed.

Comment: What does `cache error in google pagespeed` mean, **exactly**?  Show us what you are seeing.

Comment: There are lots of advertencies if i test my site with google page speed insights. It says you must leverage cache browser with the following elements.... and it returns me a lot of elements with .jpg .gif .svg .js extensions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is fine.  If it isn't working, mod_expires can't be enabled.

- Enable mod_expires: `a2enmod expires`
- Restart Apache: `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
# Enable browser caching for most static assets, 1 month
<filesMatch ".(css|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|pdf|js|ico|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
</filesMatch>
```

Change the `max-age` to the number of seconds you want. Mine is set to 1 month.

This uses cache-control instead of expires. Cache-control is the more modern solution. A good overview of the differences and how to use each is here:
http://dev.mobify.com/blog/beginners-guide-to-http-cache-headers/